# CartoDB / ArcGIS online map to show roadworks in a city

Tags: google-maps, carto, arcgis-online

I want to create a map that shows roadworks based on start and end time in the City of Aarhus (second largest city in Denmark) using CartoDB (or ArcGIS online) similar to http://roadworks.org/ - I haven't been able to find any examples that shows this using CartoDB. I'm looking for a simple solution.

Comment: Where is your source data coming from? can only find Google Traffic as a source https://www.google.com/maps/place/Aarhus,+Denmark/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x464c4cb15397788b:0x8c4dd7d9912ea2af!5m1!1e1?sa=X&ei=i-IGVdT8LYzloASow4CYDA&ved=0CB8Q8gEwAA

Comment: Please note that GIS.SE is not a site on which to solicit work or contractors to perform work.

Comment: @Mapperz Sourcedata is coming from a variety of formats csv, wfs (GeoServer). A danish wfs source called vejman (roadwork) http://vmgeoserver.vd.dk/geoserver/VD/ows?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities

Comment: @ChrisW okay - no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just want to use different kinds of markers on a map and filter them. There're some similar examples (taken from [the gallery](http://cartodb.com/gallery/)):

- http://map.calvertfoundation.org/#2/8.00/-32.00/nokia-day/stories
- http://guia-das-cidades-da-copa.g1.globo.com/bahia/turismo-e-viagem/pt/como-chegar/arena-fonte-nova/

And here're some related tutorials on how to do it:

- [Adding placemark icons](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/placemark_icons.html).
- [Toggle map view](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/toggle_map_view.html).

Bonus:

- [Custom interactivity](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/custom_interactivity.html).
- [Visualizing a GSP track](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/gps_track.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your ideas - very interessting. But Im looking more for a solution that makes it possible to filter dates. I have found this -
http://bl.ocks.org/iriberri/7335eebcdda69b0b4f80
- but need to be able to search for specific dates.

Comment: That example is perfect, you just need to change the slider with a datepicker and probably change slightly `"select * from us_po_offices where built >= '" + start + "' and built <= '" + end + "'"` so it filters from the beginning of the day until the end (take a look at PostgreSQL date functions: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html).